# Comentarios en android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

¿Cómo puedo poner comentarios para las clases importadas en el gradle para leerlos como descripción al implementar un método de esa clase?

> La **pregunta** es de android, aunque supongo que también vale para Intellij IDEA.

Comment: ¿Y para que quieres hacer eso? si no es mucho preguntar

Comment: @JeCuRo Se hace por propositos de documentación.

Comment: Ah ok te dejo mi solución. Suerte!, Es un interesante pregunta  que puede ayudar a más gente , puedes por favor editarla y añadir más detalles como por ejemplo que lo que has dejado más abajo en tu comentario:   " ....lo que quiero es poner comentarios a los métodos.de las clases que añado como dependencias en el gradle....." Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me temo que no puedes acceder al código de las librerías que importas mediante `Gradle`  básicamente por que añades los `.AAR` como dependencia, pero no el código en sí.

Desde mi punto de vista tienes dos soluciones:

1. Clonar el repositorio y añadirlo como una librería a tu proyecto,
   así podrás acceder a las clases.
2. Crear tu clase que extienda de la clase que vas a usar de la
       librería cuya dependencia tienes en Gradle y luego sobrescribir los
       métodos

Answer (score 1):

Te refieres a lo que se conoce como [Javadoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc)

Puedes agregar comentarios antes de la declaración de tu método con los contenedores `/**` y `**/`

Despues de agregar los comentarios puedes ir a `Tools` > `Generate JavaDoc` para generar la documentación de tu aplicación.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/generate-javadoc-dialog.html

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/viewing-inline-documentation.html

Comment: Gracias Elenasys, si es un javadoc, pero eso funciona con las clases que yo mismo implemento, lo que quiero es poner comentarios a los métodos de las clases que añado como dependencias en el gradle, Por ejemplo si incluyo la libreria picasso que es de square, cada método tiene su propio comentario y yo lo que quiero es poner editar y poner el mío para ese método, o añadir una descripción mía a ese método. Gracias